# Limits set with \mathclap are invisible in final pdf

Tags: pdftex, mathtools

I have a strange problem when typesetting sums, integrals etc. with long limits. Using the `\mathclap` command from `mathtools`, I want to type something like this

$
A = \int\limits_{\text{a very long limit that would look prettier with mathclap}}^\infty \mathrm{d} x x^2
$

(unfortunately mathclap isn't supported here it seems). However, anytime I try to use `{\mathclap{...}}`, like in this example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\Delta \varphi = 2 \int_{\mathclap{0(\frac{b}{r} \to 0 as r \to \infty)}}^{w_1} d w \left( 1 - w^2 \left( 1 - \frac{2M}{b} w \right) \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

all I get is something like this

[image]

No error codes or warnings are shown, it just doesn't render the lower limit, and I have no idea why. I'm using MiKTeX and TeXMaker on a Windows 10 machine. Normally I use pdfLaTeX to compile my .tex-files, but I've also tried XeLaTeX, to no avail.

Comment: could you just add a MWE starting with `\documentclass` etc... people willing too help will have faster go at copying pasting rather than recreating the whole mess, even if short.

Comment: and add a definition of your `\dif`.

Comment: I have no problem with `pdflatex` although the result is ugly. Thus, please check if your MikTeX install is up-to-date.

Comment: Sorry about the missing MWE, i also just threw out \dif and replaced it with `d`. Formatting is hard :P

Comment: Your MWE produces [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3uYv8.png) with the lower limit showing, but overprinting the integral sign, and `as` appearing as math

Comment: As jfbu pointed out, running Update on Miktex showed that there was a relatively recent update for mathtools I didn't have installed. Installing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more a comment than an answer, but it's too complicated for a comment.

i don't know why your lower limit is disappearing; i don't get that result.
however, if you're going to use `\mathclap`, you almost certainly want to use `\limits` on this integral so that the lower limit doesn't overprint the integral sign.  and the "as" is almost certainly text, not two variables
multiplied with the "r".

finally, `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so there's no reason to load both.

here's the result after those changes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\[
\Delta \varphi =
 2 \int\limits_{\mathclap{0(\frac{b}{r} \to 0 \text{ as } r \to \infty)}}^{w_1} d w
 \left( 1 - w^2 \left( 1 - \frac{2M}{b} w \right) \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: I was aware that I should use \limits, but wanted to rule out \limits was somehow messing with \mathclap. Thus I made a 'minimal' example without using too much at once. Anyway, running Update on MiKTex both as Admin and User and restarting TeXMaker did the trick. Thanks for the input though, I appreciate it.